# Checking if checkboxes and radios are checked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been through nearly every answer on this topic and I've had a hard time coming up with a solution.

Basically, I'm trying to click a button that runs a function which checks to see if a radio button or check box is selected.

Later one I'd like to be able to test for different combinations of these selections.

This is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function custom_urls(){
      var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
      var option2 = document.getElementByid("option2");
      var bonus = document.getElementByid("bonus");                                          

      if ( option1.checked ){
        alert("Option1 is checked!");
      }
    }


  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type = "radio" id = "option1" > Option1 </input></br>
  <input type = "radio" id = "option1" value = "option2"> Option2 </input></br>
  <input type = "checkbox" id = "bonus" value = "bonus"> Bonus </input></br>
  <button type = "button" onclick = "custom_urls()">Click Me</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried putting:

```
if(option1.checked == true)
```

and

```
if(document.getElementById("option1").checked == true)
```

Comment: This could be done fairly easy with jQuery. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: also, you can't have 2 elements with the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your code has typos. It must be `document.getElementById`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function custom_urls(){
      var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
      var option2 = document.getElementById("option2");
      var bonus = document.getElementById("bonus");                                          

      if (option1.checked){
        alert("Option1 is checked!");
      }
    }


  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type = "radio" id = "option1" > Option1 </input></br>
  <input type = "radio" id = "option2" value = "option2"> Option2 </input></br>
  <input type = "checkbox" id = "bonus" value = "bonus"> Bonus </input></br>
  <button type = "button" onclick = "custom_urls()">Click Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple sollution like this:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox_id');

if (checkbox.getAttribute('checked') !== null) {
    // .. do something
}
```

Comment: No, that gets the `checked` attribute which is the `defaultChecked` value.

Comment: Oh, really, sorry for that.

Comment: Also, [`getAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9) returns a string, comparing to `null` doesn't make much sense. It will either be 'checked' or '' (empty string), but due to browser variability, it's better to read the `checked` or `defaultChecked` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues:

```
<input type = "radio" id = "option1" > Option1 </input></br>
```

Input elements have no content and no closing tag. BR elements are also empty and have no closing tag (you have written it as a closing tag). If you are using XHTMl served as XML, then you should use

```
<option ... /><br />
```

but no one serves content as XML, so just use plain HTML.

Option2

Duplicate IDs are invalid. To be successful, form controls must have a name attribute and be in a form, they don't need IDs. Radio buttons require a group with the same name, if you only have one then you can't deselect it without resetting the form (or using script).

Your HTML should be something like:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="rb0" value="option1" > Option1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="rb0" value="option2" > Option2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bonus" value="bonus"> Bonus<br>
  <button type="button" onclick="custom_urls(this)">Click Me</button>
```

Then your function can be:

```
function custom_urls(button) {
  var form = button.form;
  var option1 = form.rb0[0];
  var option2 = form.rb0[1];
  var bonus = form.bonus;

  if ( option1.checked ){
    alert("Option1 is checked!");
  }
}
```